# Is it possible to migrate data from MySQL to PostgreSQL through Django dumpdata?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm trying to convert my database from MySQL to PostgreSQL, and I'm using AWS RDS. I was trying AWS DMS to migrate data, however it didn't work well and was complicated.

While struggling with that, an idea came to mind. What if I use migrate migrations to the new PostgreSQL, and dumpdata from MySQL and loaddata to PostgreSQL? Would that work? Does anyone have experience to migrate database? Am I approaching a right direction?

Comment: It should work. The data is dumped in an agnostic json format. I do recall small little issues arising auto-incremented fields but your specific problems will surface when you try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this in the past and it has worked, but with some bumps in the road. Be sure your database is frozen - you might want to put users with access into read-only mode.

Good luck.

Comment: Do you remember what kind of bumps you had? I just finished `manage.py loaddata` and it seems to be working very well for now. Like you advised, I'm gonna freeze MySQL database for a while, and then delete it when I'm sure everything is okay.

Comment: The issues I ran into were with JSON in columns from the Wagtail CMS. Getting the keys within the JSON blocks made things tricky!

Comment: That CMS library looks great. I should try it later :) So, it sounds like it would be okay if not using Wagtail CMS?

Comment: As long as you're not doing anything too exotic with JSON in fields, I haven't run into any other problems. I'd take a wait-and-see approach - hang on to the old database for a while to make sure all is okay. In fact, do a `mysqldump` and gzip the backup to keep it, even after you shut it down. I've moved to PostgreSQL everywhere and have been very happy with it!

Comment: Alright, thank you for the advise. Will keep the old db for a while as you advised that. Thanks!

Comment: `--natural-foreign` was my friend when migratiing a django-cms project exactly the same way. Also, after the initial `./manage.py migrate` on postgresql, I had to manually truncate contenttypes and permission tables (otherwise, their mappings from existing groups/users was not correctly, made loaddata fail).